# Encapsulation of Text property in user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, encapsulation

I am creating a custom label inheriting UserControl. To encapsulate Text property, I have created below script.

```
    [Browsable(true)] // <--- This is necessary to show the property on design mode
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return label1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that even though I set the Text property on designmode, when I rebuild the project, the text returns to default value.

```
    public UCLabel() // <--- this is the class constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackColor = Global.GetColor(Global.UCLabelBackColor);
        label1.ForeColor = Global.GetColor(Global.UCLabelForeColor);
        label1.Text = this.Name;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Obviously, the value of 'text' is not serialized.*

To solve this problem you just have to add
the [DesignerSerializationVisibility Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility.aspx)

```
    // This is necessary to show the property on design mode.
    [Browsable(true)] 
    // This is necessary to serialize the value.
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)] 
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.label1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.label1.Text = value;
        }
    }
```